# Habilitar e desabilitar um botão de edição de formulário - com PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho a seguinte situação:
Tenho um página (ex: EDITAR.PHP) que vai ser onde será editado as informações que anteriormente foi cadastrada por um formulário (Formulário de cadastro de usuários). 
A questão é, no final dessa página EDITAR.PHP, terá um botão salvar (onde será redirecionado para uma função que fará o INSERT na base). Gostaria de saber se com PHP eu conseguiria que, ao abrir essa página tivesse alguma validação pra fazer com uma consulta ao banco pois quando esse determinado usuário fosse de sexo = M, por exemplo, não habilitasse o botão SALVAR, deixando visualizar mas não salvar.

ESTÁ TRAZENDO AMBOS OS SEXOS COM O BOTÃO DESABILITADO

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$id = $_GET["id"];
settype($id, "integer");

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("banco");

$resultado = mysql_query("select * from tabela where id_tabela = $id");
$dados     = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
if($dados["sexo"] == "M") {
    $checkedM   = "checked=\"checked\"";
    $checkedF   = "";
} else {
    $checkedM   = "";
    $checkedF   = "checked=\"checked\"";
}   
$sqlstatus = mysql_query("select * from tabela where sexo = 'M' GROUP BY sexo");
$res = mysql_num_rows($sqlstatus);



mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Cadastro</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="salvar_edicao.php">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
  <h2 align="center"><strong>Edição de Cadastro PHP/MYSQL </strong></h2>
  <table width="390" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="165">Nome</td>
      <td width="209"><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" value="<?php echo $dados["nome"];?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sobrenome</td>
      <td><input name="sobrenome" type="text" id="sobrenome" value="<?php echo $dados["sobrenome"];?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $dados["email"];?>" /></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td>Sexo</td>
      <td><input name="sexo" type="radio" value="M" <?php echo $checkedM;?> /> 
        Masculino 
        <input name="sexo" type="radio" value="F" <?php echo $checkedF;?> /> 
        Feminino </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Gravar" <?php echo $res > 0 ? 'disabled' : '' ; ?> /></td> //Com o 'disabled' na frente trás tudo desabilitado, e com ele na frente traz habilitado.
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

NO BANCO ESTÁ ASSIM:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você chegou dar `print_r($dados); die();` para ver o que retorna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de fazer

```
if($res > 0)
<input type="submit" disabled>

else{
<input type="submit">
```

Você também pode usar o operador ternario fazendo da seguinte maneira.

```
$res = 2; // Exemplo de resultado
<input type="submit" <?php echo $res > 0 ? 'disabled' : ''; ?> />
// Se $res for maior que 0 será exibido disabled se não, não será exibido nada.
```

Sua consulta pode estar retornando mais de 1 resultado, utilize da seguinte maneira.

```
$sqlstatus = mysql_query("select * from tabela where sexo = 'M' GROUP BY sexo");
```

O `GROUP BY` ira agrupar todos as linhas que tiverem o `sexo = M`

Comment: Funcionaria onde você colocou $res =  2; Eu definir uma letra, tipo 'M', ai no input como ficaria?

Comment: Coloquei assim: $sqlstatus = mysql_query("select sexo from tabela where sexo = 'M'");
$res = mysql_num_rows($sqlstatus);
$res = 'M'; E: <?php echo $res = 'M' ? 'disabled' : ''; ?> . Ta ficando tudo desabilitado agora. @
Rafael Acioly

Comment: @TiagoIB Tente usar dois sinais de iguais `==` ou ate mesmo 3 para verificar autenticidade `===`, mas neste caso voce esta usando  `$res` para pegar um `NUMERO (mysql_num_rows)` de linhas e não uma `string`.

Comment: @ Rafael Acioly Ajustei o código da pergunta acima, de acordo com a sua sugestão porém, está retornando ambos as opções com o botão desabilitado.

Comment: Coloquei todo o meu código de como está agora. E mesmo assim está trazendo desabilitado tanto em usuários com sexo: M ou F. 
@ Rafael Acioly

Comment: @TiagoIB é claro que vai sempre ficar desabilitado, depois de usar o `$res` para pegar o numero de linhas você define ele como `2` apagando o que foi buscado no banco, apague esta linha`($res = 2)`, e dentro da condição ternaria que te passei inverta as ordens: `<?php echo $res > 0 ? '' : 'disabled'; ?>`

Comment: @ Rafael Acioly . Apaguei e continua ficando desabilitado sempre: $sqlstatus = mysql_query("select * from tabela where sexo = 'M' GROUP BY sexo");
$res = mysql_num_rows($sqlstatus); e o botão: <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Gravar" <?php echo $res > 0 ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>/>

Comment: Com eu disse antes, troque a ordem para `<?php echo $res > 0 ? '' : 'disabled'; ?>` este operador ternario é basicamente um `if` super pequeno e funciona assim: `"mostre (echo)" (operacao) ($res > 0) ?  "se for verdadeiro" : "se for falso" ?>`

Comment: @ Rafael Acioly . Acabei de colocar o código todo no topo da pergunta. Fiz bem o que você disse e por algum motivo está retornando desabilitado. O tipo de dado no banco interessa?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29273/discussion-between-rafael-acioly-and-tiagoib).

Answer (score 4):

Se acordo com sua consulta você pergunta se  o `status` é igual a 2.

Então, apenas faça uma verificação perguntando se retornou algum registro ( > 0 ). Se sim, ele mostra o botão desabilitado, `disabled`.

```
<?php

    $sqlstatus = mysql_query("select status_atividade from atividades where status_atividade = 2");

    $res = mysql_num_rows($sqlstatus);

    if($res > 0)
       <input type="submit" disabled>
    else
       <input type="submit">

?>
```

Comment: Ai lá no botão não precisa por nada? @DiegoSouza

Comment: Eu coloquei o `disabled`.

Comment: Eu não havia visto sua consulta toda... mudei meu código e estou verificando pelo número de linhas retornadas do seu `select`.

Comment: Testei e deu erro.  Funciona se o campo for uma Letra ao invés de um numero no status_atividade = 'M' ? @DiegoSouza

Comment: Acabei de editar o código acima conforme o teu exemplo. Vê onde pode tá errado. @DiegoSouza

Comment: Recomendo que não use mysql_* e sim mysqli_* ou PDO. Vou dar a resposta baseado que você já fez a correção.

Comment: Nomear a tabela de "tabela" é a coisa gente preguiçosa.

Answer (score 1):

> **EDITADO** para satisfazer a necessidade com versão antiga sem uso de **mysqli**:

```
<?php

$params = array("M",1);

// query 
$sql = "select * from tabela where sexo ='{$params[0]}' and id ={$params[1]} ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   $permission='';
    if(count($row)){
        if ($row[0]['status'] == 2) {
           $permission = ' disabled = "disabled"';
        }
    }
?>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Gravar"<?php echo $permission ?> />
```

Comment: Esse meu trabalho está todo como conexão Mysql, ai não vai funcionar a não ser que eu mude tudo. Teria como formatar essa função em uma maneira mais simples, de acordo com o método de conexão mais antigo? @IvanFerrer

Comment: Vou fazer aqui.

Comment: Deu esse erro:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\cadastro-simples\editar.php on line 32 . @IvanFerrer

Comment: O erro é na linha do: permission=''; @IvanFerrer

Comment: Obrigado por avisar, era para ser uma variável.

Comment: Só aviso que não sei se vai dar certo, pois não tem como eu testar aqui, pois não tenho php antigo aqui, no meu servidor retorna uma mensagem de código depreciado, e para de funcionar.